# How to integrate $\frac{1}{x\ln(1+x)}$?

Tags: integration, special-functions

I tried to evaluate the indefinite integral

$$\int{\frac{dx}{x\ln(1+x)}}.$$

Even Wolfram Alpha can't give any result in terms of standard mathematical functions. Here are some related integrals:

$$\int{\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(1+x)}}\,dx$$

$$\int{\frac{Li(x)}{1+x}}\,dx,$$

Unfortunately, I'm not able to solve any of them. Is there any special function related with this kind of integrals?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dx}{x\log(1+x)} + C$ being the answer. It's a well-defined function that can be expressed as a series and can also be numerically approximated to any degree of accuracy.

Comment: @Joe I'd maybe change to use a dummy variable within the integral but I agree

Comment: **No** special function related with this kind of integrals.

Comment: @HenryLee Hmmm... This is why we need to be able to edit comments after 5 minutes

Comment: The three integrals in this question do not look in any way related. Are they just something you randomly came up with? In that case it's pretty unlikely they can be integrated in terms of the known special functions

Comment: Check out [Gregory coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients).

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int\frac{dx}{x\ln(1+x)}$$
let $u=\ln(1+x)$ so $du=\frac{1}{x+1}dx\Rightarrow dx=e^udu$ and $x=e^u-1$ so:
$$I=\int\frac{e^udu}{(e^u-1)u}=\int\frac{du}{u}+\int\frac{du}{(e^u-1)u}$$
the first integral is obviously quite easy and you can note that:
$$\frac{1}{(e^u-1)}=\frac{e^{-u}}{1-e^{-u}}$$
which might look familiar to you as the sum of a geometric series, try this out and see if it comes to anything :)

Answer (score 1):

*Probably dangerous*

For an approximation, expand
$\frac{1}{\log (a+x)}$ as a Taylor series around $a=0$ and later make $a=1$.

This will give
$$\frac{1}{x\log (1+x)}=\sum_{n=1}^p (-1)^{n+1}\frac {P_n(t)}{b_n\,x^n} \qquad \text {where} \qquad t=\frac 1{\log(x)}$$

The first $b_n$ are
$$\{1,1,3,12,60,360,210,1680,15120,151200,\cdots\}$$ and the very first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(t) \\
 1 & t \\
 2 & t^2 \\
 3 &  t^2 (2 t+1) \\
 4 & t^2 \left(3 t^2+3 t+1\right) \\
 5 &  t^2 \left(12 t^3+18 t^2+11 t+3\right) \\
 6 &  t^2 \left(60 t^4+120 t^3+105 t^2+50 t+12\right) \\
 7 &  t^2 \left(360 t^5+900 t^4+1020 t^3+675 t^2+274 t+60\right) \\
 8 &  t^2 \left(210 t^6+630 t^5+875 t^4+735 t^3+406 t^2+147
   t+30\right) 
\end{array}
\right)$$
Now
$$\int \frac {dx} {x^p \log^q(x)}=\int e^{(1-p) y} y^{-q}\,dy=-(p-1)^{q-1} \Gamma (1-q,(p-1) y) $$

For a quick check, using $p=10$, I computed
$$I_n=\int_e^{e^n} \frac{dx}{x \log (x+1)}$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & \text{"exact"} \\
 2 & 0.59692 & 0.59703 \\
 3 & 0.98844 & 0.98854 \\
 4 & 1.27345 & 1.27355 \\
 5 & 1.49600 & 1.49610 \\
 6 & 1.67817 & 1.67827 \\
 7 & 1.83228 & 1.83239 \\
 8 & 1.96581 & 1.96591 \\
 9 & 2.08359 & 2.08369 \\
 10 & 2.18895 & 2.18905\\
 20 & 2.88209 & 2.88219 \\
 30 & 3.28756 & 3.28766 \\
 40 & 3.57524 & 3.57534 \\
 50 & 3.79485 & 3.79494 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Nice approximation!